# Highchart annotations event click get xAsix

Tags: highcharts, annotations

I have some annotations in my chart and I would like to get the specific day of my xAxis datetime when I click on one of those.

Comment: Hi Marcello Kabora, Could you describe your problem more precisely? Also, some live example or some sketch would be very helpful.

Comment: Yes sure try here there is no way to get the xAsix relative to the annotation : http://jsfiddle.net/rgm3puL8/

Comment: Hi Marcello Kabora, You can get the `xAxis` by `this.clipXAxis`. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lns78a25/

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not what I need :( I'm looking the specific point of the annotation relative to the xAsix and I cannot use "this" as reference but only the event passed.

Comment: Hi Marcello Kabora, By event you can get the `xAxis` only in an asynchronous function, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0pdqwzr8/